# jQuery wrong offset after applying zoom-property

Tags: jquery, css

When I'm trying to work with the jQuery function `offset();` and the CSS-property `zoom`, I'm getting weird results which I cannot interprete.
I made a JSFiddle to illustrate my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/btspacvd/

Basically when the object is normal (zoom: 1), the left-offset output is **368.5** for me. Seems legit.
Though if I increase the zoom to 1.5, the left-offset of the div is now **229**, even though it's position has only been changed by ~50px (see JSFiddle).

Is there a logic behind this?
I tried different calculations to understand why it's changed by 62.1% instead of something reasonable like 66.6%.

Comment: It's seems that this is an old issue on webkit https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105979 it's ok on FF. It seems that is not fully fixed.

Comment: I see, thank you. I guess I'll have to find a hacky work-around...

Comment: I think I am seeing this when I am on a mobile device, using an angular extension that wraps some jquery calls like offset().  I also seem to see it when I use chrome dev tools to simulate a mobile browser (but not just by narrowing the chrome window myself).   This messes up a sticky table header in special cases, but probably not often enough to be a huge concern.  Still, it's annoying.